# Language Julia: convert vector in matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, copy, julia, vec

Who can help.

To transform a vector into a one-dimensional matrix just run in Julia:

```
a = copy(permutedims([1,2,3]))
```

To transform the matrix "a" into a vector just use:

```
b = copy(vec(a))
```

If you have a matrix "[1 2 3; 4 5 6]" to transform it into a vector, just:

```
c = vec([1 2 3; 4 5 6])
```

Now how to make the vector have the form of the 2x3 matrix like:

```
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [reshape](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reshape)

```
julia> c = vec([1 2 3; 4 5 6])
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
 2
 5
 3
 6

julia> M=reshape(c,2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
```

Note that this operation does not reallocate memory, `c` and `M` share the same memory. By example:

```
julia> c[1]=10
10

julia> M
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 10  2  3
  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thks, Picaude Vicent.